# How can I make a photo album that stays on my iPhone, even when removing all other photos using windows "import"?

Tags: iphone

I would like to create a photo album that

- always remains on the phone
- is accessible even when I have no internet connection
- doesn't dissapear when I sync my phone to my computer
- still allows me to take new pictures and sync them to my computer

but I can't find how to do that?

Comment: Did you try synchronizing the album you would like on your iPhone using iTunes?

Comment: Can you elaborate on _how_ you actually import the photos? What software do you use? What steps do you follow? I ask because it's not clear to me _why_ your photo album doesn't remain on your iPhone after importing photos. By default everything you want is how it would normally work (although if you have created a custom photo album you would need to manually add any new photos you've taken to it). Finally, can you clarify what version of Windows you're using?

Comment: Jules: how do I do that? If you post it as an answer and it works, I can upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: @Konerak See my anwer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you synchronise your iPhone/iPad with iTunes, you can select to sync one or more albums by selecting them in iTunes.

**Opening information about your device in iTunes**

We need to open the device information in iTunes. [Download and install iTunes if you don't have it installed](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/). 
Then follow these steps:

1. Connect your device to your PC
2. iTunes should open automatically, if not, open it manually.
3. Select the small iPhone icon (see Image 1)

You will see a summary of your device in iTunes now.

**Adding albums to your iPhone**

We now have to select the albums that you want to save on your iPhone. Make sure you see the device information as described in previous steps, than follow these steps:

1. Click on Photos (See image 2, it's called "Foto's" there)
2. Check the synchronise Photos checkbox
3. Select the albums that you want to transfer to your iPhone
4. Click the synchronise button in the bottom right corner to transfer the photos

When the process is completed, your selected album(s) should be located on your iPhone in the Photo's app.

---

**Removing the albums from your iPhone**

In order to remove the albums from your iPhone, you have to follow the same steps as adding them. The difference is that you uncheck the albums that you don't want to be synchronised.

Please let me know if you need some extra help.

**Image 1**
[image: Select iPhone icon to see information]

**Image 2**

[image: Select Photos]

Comment: This gives a very scary popup "are you sure you want to remove existing photos and sync photos from this computer". Trying it anyway...

Comment: @Konerak Thats probably because you have synced your phone with anotjer machine. You could import your photo's first just to have an extra backup

Comment: I did so, indeed. It worked! Thanks. On a sidenote, I hate iTunes.